# CSS: forbid flex element grow because of its content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, overflow

Hello! I am now trying to create table component in React.
The problem looks simple, but hard to solve, at least for me.
Table consist of three main blocks: toolbar on the top, pagination on bottom, and table data in middle.
The idea is that table body must fill space between toolbar and pagination, and if there are more items in table, than can be shown, scrolling should be possible inside this middle element.
I am using flexbox for this solution, and it all looks quite well when there are just a few items inside:

[image: 3 items in table]

But when I add more items, overflow happens, and you have to scroll page to see bottom elements:
[image: More items in table]

I reproduced problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-browser-v09uml?file=/src/App.js

Is there any way to solve it better than settings max-height for elements?

```
export default function Example() {
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
return (<div className="root">
  <div className="tableHolder">
    <div className="header">toolbar</div>
      <div className="tableData">
        {items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div className="item" key={item}>
                item
              </div>
            );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="footer">pagination</div>
    </div>
  <div className="expectedSize" />
</div>)
}
```

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
}

.tableHolder {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.expectedSize {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 20px;
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tableData {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, I will. For future, why link on codesandbox is not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else said some helpful things, but they didn't work in my case on a real page. It is caused because this max-height was not applied, any content was getting out of it instead of somehow fitting inside.

I found a solution. Not CSS, unfortunately. I created an additional `<div>` element on the place where my table list was, and changed the real table list positioning to fixed and hid it:

[image]

```
<div ref={fillerRef} className={s.positioningElement}/>
<TableContainer style={tablePosition} className={s.tableContainer}>
  <!-- Real table internals -->
</TableContainer>
```

```css
.positioningElement {
    pointer-events: none;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

In the screenshot, you see this element shown. This `<div>` filler has `flex-grow: 1`, so it fills all available space between the table header and footer, but since there is nothing inside, it has no limit for minimal space and doesn't have this problem that I had with the original list.

Then I added listeners to the window scroll and resize events, and on these events fired I get the size & position of this filler div, and apply them to the real table list through style.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
        eventBus.emit('update-table-position')
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', updatePosition)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)

    eventBus.emit('update-table-position')
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', updatePosition)
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)
    }

}, [])
```

```js
eventBus.on('update-table-position', function () {
    const { top, left, height, width } = this.fillerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    console.log({ top, left, height, width })
    if (height < 50) {
        this.setTablePosition({
            position: "fixed",
            display: "none"
        })
    } else {
        this.setTablePosition({
            position: "fixed",
            left: `${left}px`,
            top: `${top}px`,
            height: `${height}px`,
            width: `${width}px`,
            overflow: `auto`
        })
    }
    this.forceUpdate()
})
```

Finally, the real table follows the filler `<div>` position and size and works just like I expect from it. I also had to add `pointer-events: none` to this filler div, to avoid problems with accessing the table in case the `<div>` covers it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay, will replace soon

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions can be to limit the height of `.root` element (which is a container in this case) to `100vh`, which means that the element's height will not be larger than the viewport:

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is the updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-edison-rnnb8w

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this, I think, that is the best option of that I found. Ideally would be fine to just make element size independent from its children elements, but looks like there are no solution for this in css yet...

Comment: @untured thanks for a positive feedback. Regarding your question - it actually  depends on what you mean by “make element size independent from its children”. Do I understand correctly that you want it to take the whole space even if there are less items?

Comment: No. I want not to grow if there are more items than can be shown when item maximally grown because of flex-grow, without explicitly setting maximal height of container where this table is placed. Maybe this is not completely clear from question description, I will update sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-sound-gz7xrt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @untured since you already specified `min-height: 600px;` for `.tableHolder`, and you want the element to have the height of `600px` all the time, no matter how many children it has, you can simply change `min-height` to `height`: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hypatia-59sobv. I'm still not sure that I got you correctly, let me know if I still don't fully understand your goal.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly declare element height, if possible. Because this element can be on page with another elements, what also take some space, and on different data in another tabs, or different user display resolution, this left available space can be different. I just want to have 3 blocks in this left space, and middle one takes all space it can take in this system, and won't be resized when its content is bigger than it can fit. If you take a look on first picture I have in description, you can see this situation. Middle element took all available space between upper and bottom.

Comment: @untured I'm not sure that it's possible, at least I don't have an idea of how to do so at the moment...